# How to find out if webbrowser URL contains a certain string. vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba, visual-studio-2008

How can I find out if the current url of the current webbrowser has a certain string.

This is the format I would like it to have if possible

```
If webbrowser1.url.contains("string") then
navigate to another site
end if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert the `Uri` to `String`:

```
If webbrowser1.Url.ToString().Contains("string") then
```